# Gnuplot on Mac os x

Tags: gnuplot

I've installed gnuplot on max os x (snow leopard).  Whenever I quit the gnuplot by typing "exit" or "quit" or ctrl-d, gnuplot quits but the terminal also quits with the message "[Process completed]".  Is there a way I can quit gnuplot and go back to the terminal where I started gnuplot?

Comment: How do you start gnuplot?

Comment: Just by typing "gnuplot" into terminal.

Answer (score 0):

`exit gnuplot` should get you back to the terminal